# Do we have a guideline for spoilers in answers, in terms of how old the content is?

Tags: discussion

I recently answered this question:

[Is it possible to skip The Last Jedi and still make sense of Rise of Skywalker?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225014/is-it-possible-to-skip-the-last-jedi-and-still-make-sense-of-rise-of-skywalker)

Several of the other answers have details which might be considered spoilers (they give away plot details). However, they're spoilers for a movie that's been out for 2 years.

Do we have any sort of guideline for spoilers, specifically in terms of "age" of the content?

I could understand not bothering with spoiler tags if you're going to mention that Darth Vader is Luke's father, but discussing things from a movie that's 2 years old seems like it may be spoilers for some people. Of course, as the question ages, the "age" of the movie relative to the point in time at which the question is being read will change. Should ALL spoilers be tagged as such?

Comment: To be honest I have less sympathy for someone complaining about spoilers in answers than in questions. The question sets the scope, your own fault if you then read the answers.

Comment: The whole age debate is a complete red herring. They are reading the answers to a question about a film they haven't seen. **Why on earth would anyone do that if they don't *actually* want any answers about it?**

Comment: @TARSsaysReinstateMonica - the question I linked as an example was basically asking *can you watch X without having seen Y* - but the answers were full of spoliers about Y. I was surprised, because it seems like the target audience for the question is people who haven't yet seen Y. Hence, I wondered if there was some sort of policy that spoilers were okay once a movie was past a certain age (2 years in this case) but after reading the linked dupe it seems like there is no hard policy and people are supposed to use their own judgement.

Comment: @dwizum Yes, that would be a special case where spoiler blocks in answers make sense (provided the answers still answer the question). But there age is *still* irrelevant because the target audience of the question won't have seen it in 10 years either or they wouldn't be the target audience.

Comment: @TARSsaysReinstateMonica - yes, I agree age is not relevant in this case.